# How to make F12 developer tools operate in the JavaScript context of emulated IE versions?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

With F12 developer tools in IE10, websites can be rendered as if in earlier IE versions. When doing so however, JavaScript still seems to operate in the context of IE10. Set the page to render as IE7 and run `'JSON' in window` in the console. It returns `true`. In an actual IE7 browser, it returns `false`.

Basically I want to use the F12 console to verify supported JavaScript features of earlier IE versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set both "Browser mode" and "Document mode" to IE7?
When I do a test, browser mode to IE7 and document mode to IE9 than JSON gives me a return.
When also putting Document mode to IE7 (standards) I get JSON is undefined.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice document mode can be changed. Thanks. Does this also make the console work as expected (not just JavaScript that runs on a page)? I cannot verify right now.

Comment: the javascript on a page and console behave the same and both depends on the browser mode seting. Also see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661313/difference-between-browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-internet-explorer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode