# Shouldn't "X-UA-Compatible IE=edge" header override "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" in IE10?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, internet-explorer-10

I have a simple HTML5 / ASP.NET website that I started testing in IE10 today since it released for Win7.

This is an intranet site within my organization, and I believe awhile back there was a group policy deployed to enable the **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** by default.

The thing I noticed today in testing was that even though I am adding an **X-UA-Compatible IE=edge** HTTP header (via my web.config), the site is showing in IE as:

```
Browser Mode: IE10 Compat View
Document Mode: Standards
```

I believe my HTML is actually OK though, because I can simply *uncheck* the **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** setting and when it reloads, it immediately switches to:

```
Browser Mode: IE10
Document Mode: Standards
```

So my question is simply, shouldn't the **IE=edge** header value override the **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** setting?

If not, is there any way I *can* override it?

Comment: I've discovered that setting x-ua-comaptible:IE=edge or IE=10 still results in the browser mode: IE10 Compat View, and ie sending the ie7 user-agent request header. Does anyone else think this is a bug?

Comment: I have the same issue. I set meta tag in page and custom header in web config, did not help. Any solution?

Answer (score 12):

(I'll put this here because this question ranked higher for my google search, but after more digging I actually found the answer on another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/1563. I'm not sure if they should be merged (at least not without some question editing))

This is likely happening because IE is set to "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> | Compatibility View settings)

You can't override this setting using the `X-UA-Compatible` *meta tag* but you can by sending the `X-UA-Compatible` *http header*:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

Credit goes to [Lavinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200442/lavinski) for finding this

Comment: Not sure how its working for you, but my original question clearly talks about using the http header and how it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ah sorry, must have mis-read the question (or confused this question with another I was looking at talking about the meta element).

Adding the header to using web.config defiantly worked for me though and I'm in a similar situation "display in compat view" set by group policy and our domain added to the intranet sites list.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me, try clearing existing headers before adding the new one or any others.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `X-UA-Compatible` forces *document mode* while "Compatibility View" turns on both IE7 *browser* and *document* mode -> the document mode was actually overridden by `X-UA-Compatible`.

See [Difference between "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661313/difference-between-browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-internet-explorer)