# Problems with X-UA-Compatible meta tag and browser redirect

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, conditional-statements

I'm currently working on a new web project and have some issues optimizing it for Internet Explorer (huh, who would've thought that?) ...
I want to support IE8+ but redirect IE 7 and earlier to an alternative page, recommending the download of another browser. For IE8 I want to display a message, recommending another browser, but not redirect it. In IE 9+ everything's fine.
First problem I came accross was, that IE10 always rendered the page in Compatibility Mode, using IE7 Standards and making the page look shitty. So I introduced the X-UA-Compatible meta tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,IE=9,IE=8" />
```

Then I tried to realize the redirect for IE7 and below using

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            document.location.href = "outdated.html"; 
        </script> 
<![endif]-->
```

Testing the page in IE11 in the different modes using F12 just wouldn’t do the redirect and displays the page crappy in IE7 and below, so I assume the X-UA-Compatible meta tag breaks the conditional comments. Nonetheless, without the tag all IE versions lower than IE10 are redirected even if the conditional comments says "lte IE 7" ...

I don't seem to be able to solve this myself, so any help will be appreciated! :)

Cheers, Rob

Answer (score 0):

IE by default uses compatibility mode if the website is served from localhost or intranet.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> In an enterprise environment, some areas have lower risk for
>   compatibility issues. For example, Intranet Zone websites use
>   Compatibility View by default.

You can not override that using meta tags like you do.

Instead you need to send HTTP Header:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

Similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128210/shouldnt-x-ua-compatible-ie-edge-override-display-intranet-sites-in-compatibil)

If you are using .NET then you can add this header using IIS configuration or making changes in web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Hi Kaspars,
thanks for your response! Indeed the offline testing was the reason for the automatic use of compatibility mode, didn't realize that. As it is going to be a hosted website, I think I don't need to overwrite it at all, do I?
Still, the conditional comments don't seem to work ... Any ideas?
Cheers, Rob

Comment: Hi again, I just read that IE11 totally dropped support for conditional comments and you have to have an actual copy of the browser you want to test ... Is that true? Because I think they worked last week when I still had IE10 on my Windows virtual machine ...

Comment: If you are hosting your website somewhere on internet you should be fine without doing anything. At the same time be careful if you do some demonstration for the customer on localhost or intranet. I have been there all the time explaining why the website looks broken every time I reload page. :)

Comment: All you care about is that IE7 understands those tags. And it does not matter if IE11 has dropped support for those tags or not because on IE11 you don't need to make any redirect or show message. If for the new browser versions conditional comments are dropped then browser must treat the block as a comment what it essentially is. Best way to check it is using some online compatibility tools like http://browsershots.org/