# RDP (Remote Desktop Connection) Breaking Website Formatting

Tags: css, wordpress, rdp

Link to my website: http://new.entrerock.com/

Screenshot of problem: http://new.entrerock.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/RDP-Screenshot.png

If I view the website in IE 11 on my desktop the website looks great. But if I connect to my companies RDP server and open it up in IE 11 it looks all messed up. My question is two fold. What could be causing it to mess up and is there anything I can do about it. Or is this just a limitation of RDP. Thanks

Comment: RDP doesnt affect the rendering of content from browsers.  As far as whats going on?  I'm not too sure.  Try debugging with a dev console.  Does the problem persist in Chrome and FF too?

Comment: It does not persist in other browsers. Praval's answer below seems to be the issue. Though not sure how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce the issue was to set the "Document mode" and "User agent string" to IE 7. Press F12 and scroll down to "Emulation mode" and ensure that your IE is set to Edge.

[image: Invalid settings on IE 11]

Comment: Verified mine was set to IE 7. I can set it to "Edge" but then if I close developer tools or refresh the page it reverts back to IE 7 mode. Any ideas why or how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18257208/3647123. That will allow you to set/force the header to be sent from your app to the browser to use the edge version

Comment: That topic reminded me of the http-equiv meta tag. I added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` to my sites `<head>` and its not displaying properly. Thank you for helping me with this! One last question.. Adding that won't affect how the site displays in other browsers or other versions of IE will it?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pretty sure it would only affect IE but perhaps do some extra testing with the other major browsers.