# IE10 Compatibility View when in Standards Document mode

Tags: html, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I would like to know exactly what the compatibility view browser mode does in IE10, when the document is in Standards mode. I'm aware it affects the declared user-agent string, but what else internally? Is the JS engine any different for example?

I'm sure the answer must exist somewhere on SO, but it's hiding from me.. I'd just like to know how much effort I should place on trying to avoid compatibility view for an intranet site. At first glance, everything looks OK (as I'd hope, given the appropriate document mode)

Many thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer which may be definitive although there's no source for the info.. this leads me to think I'm probably OK ignoring it as long as I don't succumb to browser sniffing? If anyone has any other input that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical, just found this. [Difference between "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661313/difference-between-browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-internet-explorer) which pretty much answers my question if this statement from mhenry1384 is accurate

> Browser Mode sets how the browser identifies itself to the web server
>   and to JavaScript.

Comment: no further discussion so I'll accept my own answer.