# IE User Agent and Document Mode?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

While testing sites in IE, I check the site in both versions

1. IE 8(Doc Mode) with Standard(User Agent) and
2. IE 8 with IE 8 Standards

In the first, site is loaded well, but wholly messed up in the 2nd.

I read lots of topics, but opinions are inconsistent and not clear.

Which is the difference and which one I should use for testing to satisfy clients if they check the site in e.g. IE8?

Comment: check if this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661313/difference-between-browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-internet-explorer

Comment: In the first scenario, are you using a modern version of IE (such as 10, or 11), and switching the Document Mode to IE 8 via the developer tools?

Comment: Yes, I switch via developer tools, not sure what to do, so that user will always see IE8 with Standard User Agent((

Comment: You can use the x-ua-compatible header with the content attribute set to "IE=8" to force IE to use IE8 standards mode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/jj676915(v=vs.71).aspx).  This will not affects the user agent string.  If you need that, you need to use IE11 Enterprise mode (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687).

Comment: Thanks for comment, when I use `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >` and check in Ie8, it again show the page in 2nd mode and not Standard, as I want (see screenshot please http://gyazo.com/d152c9f9aee750d5d1accd810c63ab3d )

Comment: In the screen shot you're looking at, the page default is IE8 standards mode.  If you're looking for IE7 Standards mode (the second option), then you'll want to set the content attribute to 'IE=7'.  For more, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/jj676915(v=vs.71).aspx