# Changing Document Mode in IE9 with Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm struggling to get a very "cleverly" coded JavaScript application working on Internet Explorer. It's currently working fine on IE7-8 but some scripts fail silently in IE9 and I haven't been able to figure out why yet. The project has a strict deadline approaching and I can't spare time for decent debugging so I'm considering forcing the page to be displayed in IE8 document mode.

This has been otherwise successful, but IE9 users who have *ever* touched their Document Mode selector and set it to IE9 mode aren't affected by the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag and get a blank page. The IE8 document mode is shown as "default" in the Document Mode menu, but the one selected by the user seems to always override the one suggested by the page.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode) question and it's accepted answer suggest that in IE8 the browser reverted to default document mode on page reload. Has this changed in IE9? Do I have any hope to reliably force IE8 document mode to IE9 users who have Developer Tools enabled?

**Edit:** I managed to fix the actual bug in time, but I'm leaving this question open because I'm still interested in an answer. The bug was related to IE9 claiming it supports CSS transitions but not providing a name for it's transitionEnd event.

Comment: Don't force people to use an old document mode. Fix the problem instead.

Comment: Is *very "cleverly" coded* the new way of saying buggy?

Comment: Eric: Fixing the problem won't be a walk in the park. The project uses RequireJS and if I try to debug, the external scripts timeout and halt the execution. If I run it without debug, the execution just stops without any error messages. epascarello: It's my way of saying buggy, overly complicated and utterly unreadable.

Comment: I'd also be very interested in an answer to this - I hope that it's like this so any "normal" IE9 user will still see the mode I set in the meta tag "X-UA-Compatible"...