# Browser mode vs document mode in IE development tool panel

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, cross-browser, ie8-browser-mode

Well, I've tried to learn about this topic from some threads, like the two mentioned below

- [IE8 browser mode vs document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx?Redirected=true

But not able to make myself clear. So can someone please answer this against my question below.

Note: I have IE 10 @ Windows 7 on my machine. Which I used as reference while drafted my query.

Suppose if I have to test a website on my machine on IE to check how it will reflect on a user machine's IE. Which point is correct. (I want my website to work well on IE 9, 8 and 7 on my user's machine on whatever windows he owns).

1. I should test my website changing only the 'browser mode' and let the 'document mode' be to default i.e. 'standards (page default).

   Doing so if my website works well across browser mode IE 9, IE 8 and IE 7; then it means it will work well on user's IE browser too. Whether he's viewing on IE 7, IE 8 or IE 9 on Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7.

OR

2. I should check changing both the 'browser mode' and the 'document mode' **AND** keeping both selected to the same version i.e. if browser mode is IE 9 then document mode should be selected for IE 9 standards and not any other).

   Doing so if my website works well across browser mode IE 9, IE 8 and IE 7; then it means it will work in same manner on user's IE too whether he's viewing on IE 7, IE 8 or IE 9 on Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7.

OR

3. I should check changing both the 'browser mode' and the 'document mode' **first** selecting one browser mode against all the documents mode i.e. browser mode IE 9 against document mode IE 9 standards, then IE 8 standards and then IE 7 standards; and then other browser mode against the same set of documents mode.

   Doing so if my website works well across browser mode IE 9, IE 8 and IE 7; then it means it will work in same manner on user's IE too whether he's viewing on IE 7, IE 8 or IE 9 on Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the *browser mode* **AND** the *document mode*.

*Document mode* specifies which rendering engine is used.

*Browser mode* specifies the user agent IE sends to the Web server and how IE processes [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=VS.85).aspx).

As a word or caution, the newer IE browser doesn't always do a perfect job at emulating the older browser.