# Why do I need special code in my HTML head tags to display my web pages in IE 10?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Been pounding on this for weeks and found that if I put

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
```

in my HTML head tags my pages will render in IE 10 and IE 10 standards just fine...
My pages are C#.net and it is my understanding that this code tells the browser to emulate IE 7?
Am I correct in my assumptions?
I have changed the code to IE=10 and the pages will render on my computer in IE 10 Documents IE 7 standards (F12), but the pages are all messed up in IE 10 standards, unless I use the above code.
Can some one please explain this to me?

Comment: `"My pages are C#.net"`- does not really sound reasonable to me; pages are HTML with optional CSS and JavaScript, IMHO.

Comment: do you know the difference between server- and client-side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 browser mode vs document mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What causes the document mode to change?

```
 The Doctype and the X-UA-Compatible meta tag and header set by the web developer.
```

Duplicate:

check following link:

[IE8 browser mode vs document mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950598/ie8-browser-mode-vs-document-mode)

Comment: Outstanding!!! Just needed some clearity on the events taking place. the link answered all my questions!